# Displaying rows for last 7 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hoping someone can tell me why this isn't working.  I give a `TextBox` a default value and then use a Query to select * where it is within 7 days.  I thought I had this working, but apparently it isn't now and I didn't change it so must have been imagining it when I saw it working.  A user can enter an integer into a text box and it uses that to modify the parameter in the query.  It concatenates a minus sign so by default the parameter passed to the query is `-7`, but no matter the value (And I debugged and ensured that the value being passed was `-7` by default).  And I know it isn't working because there are entries in the DB older than 7 days.  Did I get the query wrong?

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="newsDaySelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="20" Text="7"></asp:TextBox>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM vw_front_news WHERE newsDateStamp < DATEDIFF(day,@newsDate,GETDATE()) ORDER BY newsDateStamp DESC", conn))
    {
        int newsDate = Convert.ToInt32("-" + newsDaySelector.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsDate", newsDate);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        newsRepeater.DataSource = ds;
        newsRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that newsDateStamp is set as datetime or date in the database?

Comment: Yep, the column is a Datetime.

Comment: use dateadd instead of datediff -  dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)

Comment: That is almost working!  Except it is showing rows `older` than 7 days.  It worked when I changed to greater than.  If you put that into an Answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use dateadd instead of datediff -

```
dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate()) + 7,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Modifying my query to `SELECT * FROM vw_front_news WHERE newsDateStamp > dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())-@newsDate,0) ORDER BY newsDateStamp DESC` worked great.

Answer (score 2):

query problem

@newsDate = -7

than

```
SELECT * FROM vw_front_news WHERE newsDateStamp >= DATEADD(day,@newsDate,GETDATE())  and newsDateStamp <= GETDATE() ORDER BY newsDateStamp DESC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM vw_front_news WHERE DATEDIFF(D,GETDATE(),newsDateStamp ) > @newsDate ORDER BY newsDateStamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your query -

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_front_news
WHERE newsDateStamp BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -@newsDate, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY newsDateStamp DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, I must not have explained it clearly.  I could hard code it, but I have the `TextBox` on the asp page so that people can enter a different value if they want to easily view older topics they can.  That's why I am passing the param.